# Leaflet Marker Cluster: Popups won't open after first

Tags: leaflet, clustering, popup

I built a map using Leaflet and markercluster.js, and I'm having a strange issue where after I click on the first popup, I'm unable to open any other popup. This happens whether you close the first popup manually or not.

When I don't use markercluster.js, the popups appear as normal, so I know it has something to do with that library. This is the second time I have used this library; the first time I had no issues. I'm getting no errors in the console.

Also, I had this issue regardless of if the .openPopup() method was attached to the marker variable.

Code below:

> var puetrasList = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
>
> ```
>           for (i=0 ; i < dataStore.length ; i++){
>               var a, point;
>               a = dataStore[i];
>               lat = parseFloat(dataStore[i][0]);
>               lng = parseFloat(dataStore[i][1]);
>               title = "<strong><h2>" + dataStore[i][2] + "</strong></h2>" +
>                                   "<p>" + >dataStore[i][3] + "</p>" +
>                                   "<p>" + >dataStore[i][4] + ", " + dataStore[i][5] + "</p>" +
>                                   "<p>" + >dataStore[i][6] + "</p>";
>               marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
>               marker.bindPopup(title).openPopup();
>               console.log(marker)
>               puetrasList.addLayer(marker);
>           }
>
>
>
>           //----- Summon Map ---->
>           map.addLayer(puetrasList);
>           map.addLayer(layer);
> ```

Comment: map.addLayer(layer); what is layer?

Answer (score 3):

Use marker on click in the for loop.It will shows the popup

```
 marker.on('click', function (e) {              
    this.bindPopup(title); 

});
```